# How to serve worker.js file in Python wsgi?

Tags: python, webpack, wsgi, worker, static-files

I'm developing a web app which uses a Web Worker. I'm using Webpack to create the bundle and with a Node.js web server all works fine.

But now I should use a Python wsgi server based on gunicorn. I don't know how to serve the worker.js file. In Node.js this is not a problem because I serve the entire static directory. Is there a similiar way to serve all static files in Python? 
I have to serve the static file from the same server in order to avoid cross-origin problems.

Comment: mostly gunicorn works with nginx which serves static files. ie. Nginx (virtual host) configuration to work with Gunicorn http://pastebin.com/4cc2vEKj

Comment: @furas Thanks a lot for your answer, but I was looking for something easier. I need this only for a period of development, so I created a route for the worker. In this way it works.